# Bootstrap requires JQuery Error - Loaded JQuery But have more errors

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, jquery

I am trying to use Bootstrap to my custom theme and followed exact instructions in 
https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap
http://marvelcommerce.com/blog/intergrating_bootstrap_with_magento

However, when I load JQuery by having this in Local.xml

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/JqueryFile.js</name></action>
```

I get other errors such as:

```
prototype.js:5644 Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
fashion-hub.html:741 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).selectbox is not a function
fashion-hub.html:1221 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).selectbox is not a function
fashion-hub.html:804 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'down' of undefined
script.js:1533 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).selectbox is not a function
fashion-hub.html:190 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).UItoTop is not a function
```

Not that I also added

```
<block type="core/text" name="jquery-noConflict"><action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict()</script>]]></text></action></block>
```

to avoid conflicts.

What could have gone wrong with this. I have been trying for 3 weeks and not able to figure it out. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: for no conflict, i added this in local.xml

<block type="core/text" name="jquery-noConflict"><action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict()</script>]]></text></action></block>

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the `$` in every jquery file included. so replace `$` with with `jQuery`. only adding the `jQuery.noConflict()` will not worked.

Comment: Thanks Qaisar. I am newbie to JS. So, Do I just open all JS filles and do find/replace from ($) to (JQuery)? I mean, all dollar signs should be replaced? or only specific ones?

Comment: Also, how do I know JQuery files? are they all the JS files inside skin/js folder? Some of these files are part of extensions installed in my store.

Comment: all but no change in jquery library file..

Comment: the extension provider are already solved the js conflict

Comment: Thanks Qaisar. If extension providers resolved this, and I should not modify the JQuer lib file, then which files should I modify? is it the one related to bootstrap (bootstrap.js)? Because I get errors in different files such as in  prototype.js. Thanks again

Comment: yes check the bootstrap js remove the conflict there

Comment: It appears that the theme designer already included an old version of JQuery. If I replace it with a new version, it causes problems. can i add two and how to deal with the conflict.

Comment: You can add two jquery libraries but not the same library twice